# Circle Ci - Start react server and test via cypress

Tags: cypress, create-react-app, circleci, craco

I'm running cypress on a server started in cirleci script. Though cypress can't seam to find the local server that I just started. Here's my scripts / setup. I've also tried the cypress circlci-orb and get the same error, so was trying run things myself to help debug. Here's the script details:

```
  - run:
      name: 'Run app tests'
      command: |
        cd app
        yarn install --frozen-lockfile
        yarn lint
        yarn cypress:ci
```

package.json script:

```
"cypress:ci": "CYPRESS_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000 yarn start & wait-on http-get://localhost:3000 && cypress run"
```

Error:

```
$ craco start
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.208.3/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /root/project/app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

.....
react startup output
......
```

**Cypress tests are kicked off and get the following error**

```
We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.

We received this error at the network level:

  > Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this? i'm having the same issue but only when running more than one test

Comment: Just posted the solution @alextrastero :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The solution:* **Up your resource class!** In your `circleci/config.yml`

```
jobs:
  continuous-integration:
    resource_class: large
```

It was non obvious as there were no memory/resource warnings, but according to the circle ci team:

`When the machine runs out of memory processes are killed which could include the server.`

That server was the `cra-server` i was trying to start. I upped the resource class and voilà it ran and was found by cypress! In our case we bumped it from a medium to a large class, but may be different for you.

Here's the available resource classes you can use:

https://circleci.com/product/features/resource-classes/

Comment: Yes, my issue was also related to resources, I had `resource_class: small` so i just had to remove it for it to work, thanks for adding your answer!